# CD permission denied after changing directory permissions

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, nginx

I'm working through https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 .

I want to modify the nginx server blocks which I've created with the tut. I tried to cd in and was denied. checking a 'stat' I found that the directory had 644 permissions. Therefore I performed:

```
deploy@server:~$ sudo chmod 646 /etc/uwsgi/sites/
[sudo] password for deploy:
deploy@server:~$ stat /etc/uwsgi/sites/
  File: '/etc/uwsgi/sites/'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 9041h/36929d    Inode: 97128482    Links: 2
Access: (0646/drw-r--rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-01-25 12:33:48.149427949 -0500
Modify: 2017-01-19 16:15:32.658184778 -0500
Change: 2017-01-25 12:33:45.812411548 -0500
 Birth: -
```

But when I try to cd in I get the same problem:

```
deploy@server:~$ cd /etc/uwsgi/sites/
-bash: cd: /etc/uwsgi/sites/: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

```
 deploy@server:~$ sudo chown deploy /etc/uwsgi/sites/
[sudo] password for deploy:
deploy@server:~$ cd /etc/uwsi/sites/
                                       -bash: cd: /etc/uwsgi    /sites/: Permission denied
deploy@server:~$
```

Comment: directories need execute permissions So either 775/770 or 755/750. By the way: 646 is pretty odd!? I would expect 664/660 or 644/640 as normal. "others" allowing more access than "group" seems odd to me.

Comment: so that would be: `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` for files `find . -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;` for directories.

Answer (score 0):

It being 644 shouldn't be a problem but you could try to change the owner of the folder with chown.

```
chown deploy /etc/uwsgi/sites/
```

Did that help you?

Comment: please see edit: